# Waive off time limit on accepting answer to a closed question

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, accepted-answer

This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441507/why-does-bar-bar1bar-not-create-any-object-instances/14441531#14441531 got closed as exact duplicate. No problems with that, but there is already an answer (which answers my question, but that's not relevant for now). I am clearly not going to get any more answers, so why not let me accept the one that's there right away?

Comment: You can accept the answer just fine and you did it; What's the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem exactly is the time limit on accepting it. I had to wait 15 minutes to accept it, which in this case served no purpose.

Comment: While technically true, I don't see any point in allowing to accept once a question is closed. What if it's closed within short time, you accept then the question is reopened? We are left with possible hijacking of the system.

Comment: You are right, but if I understand it right, it takes 5 people to close a question (and 5 to reopen it? not sure about that). So hijacking the system is unlikely.

Comment: Yes indeed, 5 different users with 3K rep or more (or the OP and 4 others) but still, it just feels wrong.